# Unable to copy data from another sheet to main sheet. Error on execution vba subscript out of range error 9 on calling sub copy

Tags: excel, vba

to get the data from website in sheet2

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    strSearch = Range("a1")
    With Sheet2.QueryTables.Add( _
                     Connection:="URL;https://iban.codes/validate/ " & strSearch & "&safe=active", _
                     Destination:=Sheet2.Range("a5"))`

       .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With
    Call copy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheet2.UsedRange.Delete
    End Sub
```

to copy the data from sheet2 to sheet1

```
Sub copy()
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5") 
 End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get, if any, what happens and what do you expect to happen? To me it looks like it's copying exactly what you are telling it to.

Comment: Everytime i run a macro it gets error subscript out of range error 9 pop up.

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Also: All this should be in your question body, consider adding it by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: On calling the sub copy. I am getting a error.

Answer (score 0):

Sub script was out of range because my excel sheet name was different. I changed it & it worked.